# Ruby: asynchronous actor/message "society"?

Tags: ruby, asynchronous, actor

The vision:

- I code up regular ruby classes, arbitrarily organized into files.
- Each class behaves as if it were a actor with particular job duties
  and who responds to requests.
- My application consists of a society of
  these actors performing their tasks asynchronously, passing messages
  to each other and asking for data.
- While everything is running, at
  any time, I (as "god") can pause an actor or kill an actor or edit
  the code of an actor and respawn it.  Again, this is while all the
  other actors are still running; in essence this allows me to modify
  my program while it's running by killing a particular actor, revising
  its code, and respawning it.
- Let's assume that in my code for each
  actor I have written comprehensive exception handling such that if I
  kill, revise, and respawn another actor, the first will go on working
  and not crash.

Question: Does this exist?  How can I most easily implement it?

Comment: I haven't used it, but I immediately thought of [Celluloid](http://celluloid.io/), "Actor-based Concurrent Objects for Ruby"

Comment: Sounds exactly like actors in Erlang, or Akka on the JVM